# Regarding rewrite and redirect in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

I am currently rewriting urls for e-commerce and truble with matching old product url to new.

Like below, using different format on the url. Old site use SKU and new site use Id.

- [www.old-site.com/product-page.php?sku=abc123](http://www.old-site.com/product-page.php?sku=abc123)
- [www.new-site.com/productname-id.htmx](http://www.new-site.com/productname-id.htmx)

How should I approach this issue?

Thank you in advance.

I havn't tested yet but multiple of redirect url code in web.config, also using regex to read url, but I guess they can not find the using old url through new url.

Comment: Check out the IIS rewrite module. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

you can add a permanent redirect on your old URLs, it will also update the search engine, something like below

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("New URL here", true);
```